# How do I get text value from a dropdown unordered list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the unordered list:

```
<ul id="all-categories" class="categories-list nav nav-tabs text-center">
 <li class="category" >
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Liquor</a>
         <ul id="liquor-category" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bourbon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tequila</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Vodka</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Whiskey</a></li>  
          </ul>


  </li>
   ...
</ul
```

And this is the code I'm using to get the text and use it as a label elsewhere on the page:

```
var liquor_selected  = document.querySelector('#liquor-category');
      var selected = liquor_selected.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          document.getElementById("category-name-box").innerHTML = "Liquor Sub-Category Here";
      });
```

It prints the generic text, but I'd like it to print the sub-category. A little help please.

Comment: What do you mean with sub-category?

Comment: sorry, I forgot some of the code in the above example so have updated the example code. There is a nav bar with types of alcohol. One being "Liquor", The liquor category displays as a submenu when "Liquor" is clicked. I'm looking to grab the text of the selected subcategory (for ex: "Whiskey").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click handler is bound to the parent so you have to find the e.target clicked:

```
var liquor_selected = document.querySelector('#liquor-category');
var selected = liquor_selected.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById("category-name-box").innerHTML = e.target.innerText;
});
```

In jQuery you can do the same:

```
$('#liquor-category').on('click', function (e) {
  $('#category-name-box').text($(e.target).text());
});
```

or you can bind to the a selector more easily in jQuery

```
$('#liquor-category a').on('click', function (e) {
  $('#category-name-box').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! The first answer did the trick. I haven't tried the others, but I am curious, is there any benefit to using the other methods you listed? What are the differences in the 3 approaches?

Comment: jQuery stuff is a little more read-able. If it's on the page use it! Other than that having efficient event handlers is a little of an advanced topic that is explained pretty well in this video: https://bocoup.com/screencasts/more-efficient-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to achieve the following (in jQuery)

Example in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/282u8avw/

HTML:

```
          <ul id="liquor-category" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Bourbon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tequila</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Vodka</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Whiskey</a></li>  
          </ul>
          <div id="category-name-box">

          </div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#liquor-category a').click(function() {
      $('#category-name-box').text($(this).text());
    });
  })
```